# JMeter test is not executing mouse right-button clicking

Tags: jmeter, mouse, right-click

I have a scenario where I do right-button mouse clicking on a record (row in a list of some data) and choose option 'Merge to this CI' which will result in merging all available records on this list to this one particular record.
I recorded such scenario using JMeter, do some corelation etc. and when I run this test to check if it is working, I see that merge is not executing. In View Result Tree every request is green, statuses are 200, but merge is not executing. I did the same action while looking at web console and I saw, that using Jmeter I captured the same requests.
So I'm wondering that maybe it's not possible to do a right-clicking using JMeter?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter doesn't actually "click" anything, it acts on [HTTP protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) level, if your action triggers a [HTTP Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) - it will be recorded and executed.

With regards to your "problem" - JMeter reports any response with [HTTP Status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) below 400 as successful or "green", however if an error hidden behind status code 200 occurs - JMeter will not be able to detect it.

So inspect response details using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and inspect the "Response Data" tab for each and every request, my expectation is that your script is simply not doing what it supposed to be doing due to missing or incorrectly implemented [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations) so it might be the case your script is stuck at the login page.

In order to avoid such situations in future you can consider adding [Response Assertions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to your HTTP Request samplers where you can define pass/fail criteria like ensure that response contains expected data or doesn't contain the data which should not be there

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dmitri for your response. Thanks to you I dig a little deeper
At last I solved it. I found out that records have two different UNIQUE sys_id... and unfortunately I was capturing the wrong one.
Thanks once again.